# Output formatted date from Angular date filter in specific locale?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

I am using the following filter:

```
{{music.start | date : "dd MMMM yyyy"}}
```

Angular outputs the month in the computer's locale. But I let my users choose the locale in the application.

```
localize.language = "en"
```

What is a good way to tell Angular to output the formatted date in that language instead of the computer locale?

I'm fantasizing about something akin to:

```
{{music.start | date : "dd MMMM yyyy" : localize.language}}
```

But I appreciate any idea for a solution.

Comment: Hi - were you able to figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Either you

- use `toLocaleDateString()` to convert the date in your controller and append it as a property to your `music` object or
- you use symbolic names like `{{music.start| date:'shortTime'}}` - however, that does not yield the really short date without time information you are looking for.

Here's a [blog post](http://michelebusta.com/angular-tip-date-and-time-locale-formatting/) about the different ways to format locale-specific.

Your idea wouldn't work since you hand in a fixed date string and expect it to be re-formatted according to locale. That would be error-prone and hard to understand.

Comment: I don't understand how I can end up "dd MMMM yyyy" from your post and the article. I am scratching my head, so I think I need a more step by step explanation. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: I take it the important point is to get month names localized and the date format according to user locale, not preserve your cited date format (which would be Continental European)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below example in your controller

```
var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric',year: 'numeric' };
console.log(music.start.toLocaleString('en-US', options))
```

Also more information about **toLocaleString()** is present on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString  url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

The example they give is:

`<!--output 'Lundi 15 Juin 2015 à 09:03:01 GMT+01:00'-->
<p>The full date/time in french is: {{today | date:'full':'':'fr'}}</p>`

Comment: The ``locale`` parameter is not available in AngularJS, you are referring to Angular (without the JS).